# how to extract features only within a defined ROI?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, feature-extraction, feature-detection

I have 3D matrix 320x320x60 (x,y,z), and I am extracting some specific features in each direction, which features are gradient based.

Since data is 3D it takes quite long time (around 45 mins) to do the feature extraction on the whole image. which I need only the features obtained from an ROI mask [image]

Is it possible to extract features within the mask only?

I do not know how it is possible because some of the features in a specific voxel is calculated based on 1st, 2nd, and 3rd-order gradient in each direction, which considers the neighboring voxels too. 
morover, I do not want to crop the image since for reserving the coordinates.

your expert opinion is appreciated

Comment: I think you can crop the image, and then fix the coordinates (add an offset to each coordinate).

Comment: I agree to Rotem, you should crop the image tightly enough to avoid edge effects over the ROI.